# How to print the remaining columns using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Right now I have a command that prints my log file with a delimited `|` per column.

```
cat ambari-alerts.log | awk -F '[ ]' '{print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|"}' |
grep "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
```

Sample of the log file data is this:

```
2016-02-11 09:40:33,875 [OK] [MAPREDUCE2] [mapreduce_history_server_rpc_latency] (History Server RPC Latency) Average Queue Time:[0.0], Average Processing Time:[0.0]
```

The result of my command is this:

```
2016-02-11|09:40:33,875|[OK]|[MAPREDUCE2]|[mapreduce_history_server_rpc_latency]
```

I want to print the remaining columns. How can I do that? I tried this syntax adding `$0`, but unfortunately it just prints the whole line again.

```
awk -F '[ ]' '{print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" $0}'
```

Hope you can help me, newbie here in using awk.

Comment: That is an unnecessary use of `cat`. Just give the input file name to `awk`.  There is also no need to mix `awk` and `grep`.

Comment: Why are you setting FS to `[ ]`? Do you have (or can you get) GNU awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be all you need:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=5;i++) sub(/ /,"|")} 1' file
2016-02-11|09:40:33,875|[OK]|[MAPREDUCE2]|[mapreduce_history_server_rpc_latency]|(History Server RPC Latency) Average Queue Time:[0.0], Average Processing Time:[0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hassle with awk

```
awk -F '[ ]' '{
    printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
    for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i
    print ""
}'
```

or, replace the first 5 spaces:

```
awk -F '[ ]' '{
    sub(/ /, "|");sub(/ /, "|");sub(/ /, "|");sub(/ /, "|");sub(/ /, "|")
    print
}'
```

This is actually easier in bash

```
while IFS=" " read -r a b c d e rest; do
    echo "$a|$b|$c|$d|$e|$rest"
done < file.log
```

Folding in your grep:

```
awk -F '[ ]' -v date="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" '{
    $0 ~ date {
        printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
        for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i
        print ""
    }
}'
```

Comment: You can replace the loop and final print in awk with just `sub(/([^ ]+ ){5}/,""); print`.

Comment: True. Still, lipstick on a pig.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some awk that provides a somewhat more generalized approach than brute-forcing the first 5 columns:

```
awk '{
      for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        printf "%s|", $i
      for (i = 6; i < NF; i++)
        printf " %s ", $i
      }' ambari-alerts.log | grep "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)